# Universal Button AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs6, universal

how can I make a button that works for all scene and frame even tho I skipped the code layer.

For an example,

Button A on Scene 1- Normal Button
Button B on Scene 2, Layer 1- Normal Button
Button C on Scene 2, All layer - Universal Button

Example - Click Button A to go to scene that Contain Button B and Button C. Button C will work if Button A go to the first layer that contain the code for the button C. But I make another button on the same scene with Button A, but the new button take the user to Scene 2 , layer 3, for an example, the C Button wont work anymore because it skipped the code. How can I do button that works for all scene and layer?

Comment: Unclear to me what you are asking.  You aren't talking about scenes as in Flash Scenes are you? Do you mean frame, instead of scene?

Comment: Yes Flash. Im talking about both, scene and frame

Comment: I can't urge you strongly enough to abandon using flash scenes. They don't behave as expected. No one I know of uses scenes for anything at all. Instead just use a new frame to go to a new "scene" of sorts. I don't even write code using the timeline anymore so I can't help you more than that. If you are a beginner invest a few hours in some good tutorials that show you how to code in classes in .as files. That's where it's at.

Comment: Can you explain specificly on how do I achieve that? Can I copy all my code into the .as file?  Is it working that way?

Comment: Most of it should still work just copying it but some of it won't.  Google some beginner flash tutorials that aren't about coding in the timeline but instead use .as files. That's the best place to start. Lots of resources out there besides having me teach it to you here. Come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thankyou so much Neal, can I copy all of my code and paste into the .as file?

Comment: Probably not. Maybe most of it but it has to be don a certain way. It's not hard but I can't help without seeing all your code and frankly there are enough tutorials out there we shouldn't really need to do that here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kuOCZkaR3oTnpHSG44djhFZms/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kuOCZkaR3oaE5OZHU3bF8zZXc/view?usp=sharing

Here is the coding, just give 1 example for me about the coding that I gave, and I will learn to do the rest for all 19 scene.